# Is one hour connection time enough to transit at Singapore Changi (SIN) on Scoot airlines?

Tags: air-travel, layovers

I understand that Singapore Airlines is super-efficient and has great customer-centric policies in case of missed connections. However, Scoot being a Low-Cost, I am concerned.

I did check if there is a change of terminals for my connection, but I found that both the arriving and departing terminals at Changi are the same (Terminal 1). And I am guessing that's why the scheduling team at Scoot is building connections with such connection times too.

We are going just with our cabin luggage so we are not worried about baggage transfers for now!

Answer (score 2):

For most international-to-international (or domestic-to-domestic, but obviously that does not apply in Singapore) connections between flights in the same ticket, within the same terminal, one hour is usually more than enough, as there’s no immigration, no baggage claim, no customs (except in the US).

Many airports actually have much shorter minimum connection times and as long as there are no delays it’s usually effortless in any decent airport, and Singapore definitely qualifies.

The only risk is if the incoming flight is significantly delayed. Since there aren’t multiple daily flights on most long haul routes, if they can’t wait for you (which they often do up to a certain point, but that has its limits), you’ll be moved to another flight, either the same one the next day (but I’m not even sure your next flight operates every day), or rerouted through another city. In either case you’ll probably be significantly delayed (even more that the delay of the first flight).

Answer (score 1):

As a frequent user of Changi airport, I can confidently say that its enough time to connect, provided your initial flight is not delayed. I have done 20 minutes from arriving at airport to gate before. Usual procedure is as follows.

1. Get out from the aircraft.
2. There may be a security check, but very rare.
3. Go to your departure gate. It will be printed on your boarding pass.
   There are screens that displays it too.
4. Go through security check. Each gate will be having a security
   checking point and a holding area where you can sit till boarding.
   The security people are friendly and will help you.
5. Wait inside the gate and board the plane.

If you are on a single ticket with connection, no need to worry as Scoot will handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in my experience in Singapore, that should be enough. As @Anish Sheela mentioned, if there are any issues with the first flight, Scoot should be aware of the situation and help out as necessary (provided the two flights are booked on the same ticket).